# I don't understand why the first one is right, but the second fails

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I really don't know what is going on. It worked the first time, then when I try to do the second time it fails

I already checked spelling and found nothing. I am lost without help

I pointed out with a `//comment` the error line :)

Just in case my code is not self-explanatory, I want to get the second digit using the `[1]` selector

**My code is:**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        españolizar("55","44");
    }
    static void españolizar(string str, string str2)
    {
        string[] list1={"cero","un","dos","tres","cuatro","cinco","seis","siete","ocho","nueve","diez","once","doce","trece","catorce","quince"};
        string[] list2={"nivelarindexes","dieci","veinti","trei","cuare","cincue","sese","sete","oche","nove"};

        int numero = int.Parse(str);
        string strNumero = Convert.ToString(numero);


        int primerDigito = int.Parse(Convert.ToString(strNumero[0]));
        int segundoDigito = 0;

        if (strNumero.Length > 1)
            //this is the one that fails
            segundoDigito = int.Parse(Convert.ToString(strNumero[1]));
            //\-------------------------/
        }

        Console.WriteLine(strNumero);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: What the bleep is going on here?!? Why are you converting the same values to and from strings so much? it hurts my brain!

Comment: @musefan the toStrings inside the Parse is because I was getting an error that said `can't convert from char to string` or something like that. (also, because I am newbie at C sharp)

Comment: "it doesn't work" without the error message: always -1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (strNumero.Length > 1)
{ //ADD THIS!!!!
  segundoDigito = int.Parse(Convert.ToString(strNumero[1]));
}
```

You forgot to open braces.

Comment: oh my god, and I thought I checked spelling

Comment: That probaly is a typo from inserting the comment, otherwise it wouldn't compile.

Comment: @mithril333221, was this the problem?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the number is positive (no leading minus sign), you can get the first digit:

```
strNumero[0] - '0'
```

Second digit:

```
strNumero[1] - '0'
```

You don't need to call any fancy parsing functions to convert a single digit.

Comment: interesting, I will try that tip

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need the `char` and cast back and forth if you need the `string` anyway.  Then you could also use [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx).

```
String str = "56";
int firstDigit = 0;
int secondDigit = 0;
int.TryParse(str.Substring(0, 1), out firstDigit);
int.TryParse(str.Substring(1, 1), out secondDigit);
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("first digit:{0} second digit:{1}",firstDigit,secondDigit));
//result=> "first digit:5 second digit:6"
```